# Google Analytics Realtime Api Quota monitoring

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is there any way to monitor "Core Reporting API and Real Time Reporting API" usage?

According with Limit and Quotas section these specific API have a limit of :

-10,000 requests per view (profile) per day
-10 concurrent requests per view (profile).

Will be interesting to know :

- How many requests left there are for a specific view/(profile)
- From where most of the requests are coming) (IP address/Google Profile)

We are a large organisation with lot of applications using these APIs and employees make use of them on daily bases through google spreadsheet,
over the last few days we are retrieving quite often/soon the error Quota Error: profileId ga:xxxxxxhas exceeded the daily request limit. [403]
and we would like to understand from where the most of the requests are coming from

Comment: There is no way to programmatically ask google how much of your quota is left.  There is also no way of tracking which application is making all the requests.    There is also no way of extending the 10k per view limit.  I am not much help sorry.

Comment: Option / idea: If you create more then one view under the web property you could assign different people access to the different views but they wont have the older data that is under the first view you have.

Comment: I had the same Idea about create separate views , but as you said you won't have historical data on it :(

Comment: I have been working with the API team trying to get them to consider adjusting this quota.   I will have to double my efforts you are not the only one who has this problem   Sent them a link to your question.  Another persons point of view wont hurt.